# OnSubmit Safari not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I tried to call a function on form submission:

```
<form onsubmit="ShowLoading()" method="post" class="std" 
      id="masterformer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It worked well on Chrome and Firefox but on Safari; it's like my function doesn't have the time to load. The alert works. What's going wrong?

```
function ShowLoading() {
    var loading_screen = pleaseWait({
        logo: "logoloader.png",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.94)',
        loadingHtml: ""
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Updated grammar and split the code so it fitted without scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can show loading only when using ajax submit otherwise page will get redirected.

You can use following code to achieve this

```
$('#masterformer').on('submit',fucntion(){
  // do Ajax Submit Here 
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST'
    ...................
  })
  ShowLoading()
})
```